# Writing R function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to write a function that computes `pairwise_t_test` for a given covariate in my data frame.

```
pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
    pwc <- pairwise_t_test(data = df, formula = covariate ~ group, paired = FALSE )
    print(pwc)
}


pairs(df = df_test_TS, covariate = "is_donor", group = "w.contextual")
```

And I also tried :

```
pairs(df = df_test_TS, covariate = is_donor, group = w.contextual)
```

But they return:

> Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
> ✖ Column `group` doesn't exist.

Or:

> Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
> ✖ Column `covariate` doesn't exist.

The variables in are in fact names of columns in the data frame so I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is coming from the fact that df doesn't have a group or covariate column:

```r
as.character(covariate ~ group)
[1] "~"         "covariate" "group"
```

thus the formula has will push `pairwise_t_test` to look for covariate and group in the data.frame

```r
pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
    covariate <- substitute(covariate)
    group <- substitute(group)
    pairwise_t_test(data = df, formula = as.formula(paste0(covariate, "~", group)), paired = FALSE )
}

pairs(df,  len , supp)
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2      p p.signif  p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30 0.0604 ns       0.0604 ns          

pairs(df,  "len" , "supp")
# A tibble: 1 x 9
  .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2      p p.signif  p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       
1 len   OJ     VC        30    30 0.0604 ns       0.0604 ns
```

### data

```r
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the function `as.formula` like this:

```
pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
    pwc <- pairwise_t_test(data = df,
                           formula = as.formula(paste0(covariate,"~",group)),
                           paired = FALSE )
    print(pwc)
}
pairs(df = df_test_TS, covariate = "is_donor", group = "w.contextual")
```